# How to adjust a boolean mask without retyping it?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean, mask

Given a boolean mask like below:

```
mask = (
        (obiee['ADAC POSITION NBR'] == ADAC) &
        (obiee['DEPTID'] == CC) &
        (obiee['ACCOUNTING PERIOD'].isin(months)) &
        (~obiee['JRNL SOURCE'].isin(exclude_jrnl_source)) &
        (~obiee['ACCOUNT DESCR'].isin(exclude_account_dsc))
    )
df = df[mask]
```

is it possible to remove just the first (`ADAC`) filter from it? So the mask would look like:

```
smaller_mask = (
        (obiee['DEPTID'] == CC) &
        (obiee['ACCOUNTING PERIOD'].isin(months)) &
        (~obiee['JRNL SOURCE'].isin(exclude_jrnl_source)) &
        (~obiee['ACCOUNT DESCR'].isin(exclude_account_dsc))
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Hard to answer without data, but seems need assign to `ADAC` value never in column `ADAC POSITION NBR` for always return `False`s for all data:

```
ADAC = 'never value in column ADAC POSITION NBR'
```